# How to handle OS Dependant manifest.xml?

Tags: ros, manifest.xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am working with a double gnulinux/xenomai system. The switch from one to the other is done like Orocos does with the "OROCOS_TARGET" env variable. But When I have a package depending of another, I need to define 2 different manifest, for exemple :

```
<export>
    <cpp cflags="-L${prefix}/lib -larp_core-gnulinux"/>
</export>
```

or

```
    <export>
    <cpp cflags="-L${prefix}/lib -larp_core-xenomai"/>
</export>
```

How could I handle this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11856/how-to-handle-os-dependant-manifest.xml-?/) by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 352 on 2011-11-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can restrict a specific set of flags using the `os` parameter of the `<cpp>` tag, like this:

```
<cpp os="osx" cflags="-I${prefix}/include" lflags="-L${prefix}/lib -Wl,-rpath,${prefix}/lib -lrosthread -framework CoreServices"/>
```

For more details, see the [Manifest XML tags reference](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rospkg/html/manifest_xml.html).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on 2011-11-08**:
thans for this usefull link. I tagged it preferred because it is the ROS way. But I'll be use the orocos one as my package is an orocos one :)

**Comment by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on 2012-04-16**:
do you know how ROS detects the current OS ? more precisely, how does he knows between gnulinux and xenomai the one to choose ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Orocos has a special mechanism such that you don't have to put any `<export>` statement in the manifest.xml file, but can use a generated pkg-config file instead.

In your CMakeLists.txt file:

```
orocos_library( arp_core apr_core.cpp )
orocos_generate_package() # last line in your CMakeLists.txt file
```

it will generate a .pc file alongside your manifest.xml file with the correct -L and -l flags.

This .pc file will be automatically used by depending on the arp_core package, as usual in another manifest.xml file:

```
<depend package="arp_core" />
```

For the documentation of CMake macros, see [the Orocos Toolchain CMake wiki](http://www.orocos.org/wiki/orocos/toolchain/getting-started/cmake-and-building)

---

Originally posted by [psoetens](https://answers.ros.org/users/1336/psoetens/) with karma: 76 on 2011-11-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on 2011-11-08**:
oh yes, this orocos_generate_package is not in all my packages (including arp_core). This must  happened when migrating from different orocos versions.